# Jackson json enum not deserializing correctly

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am having problem deserializing a json string into java object . It is not working as expected. I want the enum code in model

My test:

```
class ConversionTest {

    private String input = "{\"model\":1}";
        
    @Test
    void convertJsonToTestModel() throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        TestModel m = mapper.readValue(input, TestModel.class);
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(m));
        assertTrue(m.isModel()==TestEnum.ANYORDER);
    }
    
    @Test
    void convertTestModelToJson_EnumShouldBeCode() throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        TestModel m = mapper.readValue(input, TestModel.class);
        
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(m));
    }
}
```

Output:

> {}
> {}

Source:

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class TestModel {
    
    private TestEnum model;

    public TestEnum isModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(TestEnum model) {
        this.model = model;
    }
}
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonValue;

//@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)
//@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.NUMBER)
public enum TestEnum {
    
        @JsonProperty("0")
        ANYMATCH(0),   
        @JsonProperty("1")
        EXACT(1),
        @JsonProperty("2")
        ANYORDER(2);

        public final int code;
        
        private TestEnum(int code) {
            this.code = code;
        }
        
        @JsonValue
        public int getCode() {
            return code;
        }
        @JsonCreator
        public static TestEnum decode(final int code) {
            return Stream.of(TestEnum.values()).filter(targetEnum -> targetEnum.code == code).findFirst().orElse(null);
        }       
}
```

I think Create is ok i.e. TestModel m = mapper.readValue(input, TestModel.class);

whats wrong with in write value as string  code? could it be library version issue?

(note: tried removing - @JsonProperty("0"))

Comment: `isModel` should be `getModel`. Your assertion should be for `TestEnum.EXACT`.

Comment: method namet matters?

Comment: Yes, bean naming convention applies by default.

Comment: yes, its working. Reason I had isModel method is because I moved from boolean to Enum.